# Что за объект в Bundle?

Tags: android

```
Bundle [{u={"Type":10,"OrderId":"5367830"}, vib=0, title=Test Data 3, lop=2, from=66474772366}]
```

Интересует, как получить именно `{u={"Type":10,"OrderId":"5367830"}`

Comment: Интересует, как получить именно {u={"Type":10,"OrderId":"5367830"}

Comment: Это строка. bundle.getString("u");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это [JSon](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) строка. Если говорить о `{u={"Type":10,"OrderId":"5367830"}`, то это читается так. В объекте `Bundle` с ключом `u` лежит объект/класс типа:

```
int Type=10;
String OrderId="5367830";
```

Comment: Да нет. В объекте Bundle с ключом u лежит какой-то объект, метод .toString() которого вернул `{"Type":10,"OrderId":"5367830"}` :)

Comment: Ну это чистый Json объект :)

Comment: В Bundle объекты могут быть либо как Parcelable, либо как Serializable. Parcelable выводятся по-другому. Это может быть Serializable, toString() которого переопределен с использованием json. Но скорее всего, это просто строка, которую в объект JSON ещё десериализовать надо.